# Error Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:compileReleaseKotlin'. >

Tags: android

I have this error while i build my flutter apk

> e:
> C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_api_headers-1.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\zeshuaro\google_api_headers\GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt:
> (52, 8 1): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was
> expected
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:compileReleaseKotlin'.
>
> > Compilation error. See log for more details
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s

i've tried every method deleting .gradle making up new

Comment: this is because of nullable string type check your dart model  file for GoogleApiHeadersPlugin. and check string type.